# MDX request to show number of items sold by type?

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence, pentaho, mondrian

I have one data warehouse table that contain one row for each item sold.
Each row contains the item's type.

What [MDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_Expressions) request could show the number of items sold for each item type?
What (dimensions,levels,etc) would it suppose to create?

In case it is relevant, I am using [Pentaho/Mondrian/Spoon/Schema Workbench](http://mondrian.pentaho.org/documentation/workbench.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build a cube from the data warehouse you would typically aggregate rows for each product sale into totals for groups of one hour, or one day, per product. Few big cubes would support drilling down to individual product sales.

After creating a [Product] hierarchy/dimension you would create a virtual dimension based on that, using the item types, to give another way of breaking the information down.